# positions of the adverb "really"

Tags: adverb-placement

Is "really" correctly positioned in the following sentences?

> He always seems innocent when he is really not.
>
> He always seems innocent when he really isn't.
>
> He always seems innocent when he is not really.

If all are correct, what is the difference?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those sentences could be used.  Where you place "really" can have some effect on the feeling or interpretation of the intent, though:

> He always seems innocent, when he **is really not**.

This uses "really" to emphasize "not", so it makes the negative stronger.  What you are saying is basically "not only is he not innocent, but he's actually *very* not-innocent."

> He always seems innocent, when he **really is not**.

This uses "really" to directly modify the verb "is (not)", so it's just saying "in reality, he is not".

> He always seems innocent, when he **is not really**.

Here, "not really" is a bit of a *set phrase* which people usually use to mean "not very much", or "not as much as people might think", so using it in this context implies "he may be somewhat innocent, but he's not *that* innocent".

Note that part of this is because the word "really" can have two meanings:  It can either mean "in reality", or it can mean "a lot".  The "a lot" sense is stronger when used directly with "not" ("really not" or "not really"), while the "in reality" sense is a bit stronger when used in front of the verb itself ("really is (not)") (though even there it can have some of the sense of "a lot", too).